# Error in running apache services from XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp, port

I installed XAMPP a few months ago and it has been working fine.  But recently when I open it I get an error of a port being occupied.

Now whenever I start my XAMPP and run apache services I get these errors:

```
Apache Service detected with wrong path
Change XAMPP Apache settings or
Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
Found Path: ERROR: Not Able To Open Service Manager
Expected Path: "d:\my local server\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
Problem detected!
Port 80 in use by "system"!
Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure Apache to listen on a different port
```

Perhaps Port 80 is being used by some system process?

What do these errors mean and how do I deal with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reconfiguring Apache to use a different port is pretty easy.

1. Find the configuration file for Apache (it's probably in `d:\my local server\xampp\apache\conf`, but I've never used XAMPP so I'm not positive). The file will probably be named `httpd.conf`.
2. Look for a line that starts with `Port`. It will probably be `Port 80` or `Port 127.0.0.1:80`.
3. Change the 80 on the end to something else.
4. Restart your service.

As for stopping the other service, you first need to find out what it is. Since this is port 80 you most likely have another web server running. The first place to look is your Services panel (`Start > Run > services.msc`). Look for anything with `Apache`, `Web` or `Internet` in the title. You might have installed other software that bundled a version of Apache, or you might have Internet Information Server installed.

If you can't find anything obvious in Services you can look for the process that's using that port. There are tools you can download to make this easier, but using the stock tools that ship with Windows:

1. Open a command prompt (`Start > Run > cmd`)
2. Run `netstat -ao`
3. Look in the `Local Address` column for something ending with `:80` or `:http`
4. Find the `PID` for that connection (last column)
5. Run Task Manager, go to `View > Select Columns...` and enable the PID column
6. Find the executable name for that PID
7. Use Google to figure out what that process is, what it's used for, and how to turn it off (usually just a matter of finding the name it uses in the Services panel)

Answer (score 6):

My solution is much easier: **Start xampp-control.exe as admin**.
Then the apparent error gone.

I`ve not changed any port or stopped any process.

Answer (score 1):

in a case check you are using Skype  login status , first logout the skype then start appache because skype also run in port 80 , else change the http.config port as any other are you lucky number

Answer (score 1):

Yoour expected path being in question points to the fact that there may be more than one instance of mysql. Search for mysql in your Windows Explorer. If the program is looking for

> Expected Path: "d:\my local server\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k
>   runservice

Make sure your httpd.exe is in the right place. I had exactly the same problem and I moved around bin/apache folder to the right location.

Full details are here:

http://hodentekhelp.blogspot.com/2014/02/on-installing-apache-on-windows-7-64bit.html

Answer (score 0):

use netstat -bano in an elevated command prompt to see what apps are listening on which ports.

But Usually following applications uses port 80 in windows.

```
IIS
World Wide Web Publishing service
IIS Admin Service
SQL Server Reporting services
Web Deployment Agent Service
```

Stop above applications if running and check!!!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue. Few days back I had installed Apache Tomcat for JSP practice, and along with this, I was starting XAMPP to work on PHP, the problem was that both server I think use the same port, so tried stopping the Apache Tomcat from services.msc>Apache Tomcat 9.0 and when I started the XAMPP again, the XAMPP Apache server started successfully

Answer (score 0):

1. open configuration file
2. fine port 80
3. change 80 to 8080
4. Save and run again