# How to change the Apache path in xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I get this error when I run xampp from my control panel. It shows the same error for FileZilla and Tomcat as well. I have deleted the xampp folder from where it says "Found Path". How do I change the path?

```
[Apache]    Apache Service detected with wrong path
[Apache]    Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
[Apache]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
[Apache]    Found Path: "C:\swati\colg stuff\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
[Apache]    Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
```

Comment: Your xampp installation should be in direct C: drive not in any sub-directory :)

Comment: Search in your httpd.conf (xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf) for the current path and change it everywhere where you find it (with CTRL + F or CTRL + H).

Comment: Your Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124599/trouble-with-apache-in-xampp-after-multiple-apache-installs

Comment: Did you installed apache OR xampp Twice ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you reinstalled the XAMPP apache, but the previous apache is still running in the background. To verify it, type services in the search window and open it. Check if apache is running still, if yes, double click on that and copy the service name. Then, type cmd in search window, run as administrator and type as follows:

sc delete "service_name"

service_name is usually "Apache 2.4".

When you get a success message like this "serviceDelete Success", restart your computer and try starting your XAMPP, it should work.