# XAMPP problems after delete Apache24

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

First time I was using Apache24, MySQL server and PHP5
but I got confused so I deleted manually and unsinstalled

After that I installed XAMPP, but I get an error on MySQL and Apache:

```
> Apache Service detected with wrong path Change XAMPP Apache and
> Control Panel settings or Uninstall/disable the other service manually
> first Found Path: "C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice Expected
> Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284271/error-in-running-apache-services-from-xampp

Comment: thanks X.LAnt, i was do like the tutorial at your link, but didnt work, than i try to edit the error on REGEDIT, i replace the path to extended , and work .....  Alhamdulillah :)

Answer (score 0):

1.Open task manager and find process httpd.exe and end this task 
2.Go to this path c:\xampp\apache\bin\
and double click on httpd.exe